# What is best way to remove ProgressDialog

Tags: android

I have created a progress dialog by

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = null; // create instance variable of ProgressDialog
int dialogID = 1;
//to create progress dialog

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
progressDialog.setMessage(message);
progressDialog.setIcon(android.R.id.icon);
return progressDialog;
}

// to show progressdialog 
showDialog(dialogID);
```

To remove the dialog I am able to use any of the following three approaches

**approach-1**

```
if(progressDialog != null){
progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

**approach-2**

```
if(progressDialog != null){
    progressDialog.cancel();
    }
```

**approach-3**

```
removeDialog(dialogID);
```

I found second approach is more effective than first approach. and if I have to use with more than one progressdialog it is easier to use approach-3. But what is the best way to destroy a progressdialog and How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cancel();` is better than `dismiss()` because according to docs:

> Cancel the dialog.  This is essentially the same as calling `dismiss()`, but it will also call your `DialogInterface.OnCancelListener` (if registered).

`removeDialog()` is deprecated so that would be the worst way.

Comment: is that true for `progressDialog.setCancelable(false)` uncancelable dialogs? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think below way is the best to dismiss the progress bar from screen:

```
if(progressDialog.isShowing())
{
   progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: I found out that sometimes dismiss method throws badwindowtoken execption, so it is advised to put in try/catch clause.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to achive. If you want to create the Processdialog everytime with a new message, you need to use the `onPrepareDialog()` Method or you use `removeDialog()` Method on a shown Dialog. Because the next time you use `yourDialog.show()` the `onCreate()` Method is called again, if you just dismiss your Dialog its not called the next time you show it. `onPrepareDialog()` is called everytime.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html